# How can we characterize $\tau\le t$ for $\tau:=\{t\ge0:x(t)\in B\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stopping-times

Let

- $E$ be a set;
- $x:[0,\infty)\to E$;
- $B\subseteq E$ and $$I:=\{t\ge0:x(t)\in B\};$$
- $\tau:=\inf I$.

> Let $t\ge0$. Are are we able to show that
>
> 1. $\tau\le t$;
> 2. $\exists s\in I:s\le t$
>
> are equivalent? If not, can we fix (1.) and/or (2.) in a sensible way?

(2.) clearly implies (1.). Assume (1.) and $$\forall s\in I:s>t\tag3.$$ We can immediatlely conclude that $\tau=t$ and hence $$\tau\not\in I\tag4.$$ So, unless we are assuming $\tau\in I$, this doesn't seem to yield a contradiction.

I'm willing to assume that $E$ is a topological space, $B$ is closed and $x$ is right-continuous, if any of these assumptions is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed (2) implies (1): if $s \le t$ for some $s \in I$ then $\tau = \inf I \le s \le t$.

The converse is true when $E$ is a topological space, $B$ is closed and $x$ right-continuous (and these assumptions are actually the good assumptions for that, you have simple counter-examples if you remove one assumption).

Indeed, if $\tau  \le t$, then for every integer $n \ge 1$, one can choose $t_n \in I$ such that $t \le t_n \le t+1/n$. The right-continuity yields $x(t) = \lim_{n \to +\infty} x(t_n) \in B$, since $B$ is closed and contains every $x(t_n)$.

Comment: Huh? I didn't argue indirectly to prove that 2 implies 1. In fact, your argument is exactly what I've got in mind when I wrote that this implication "clearly" holds.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I have just modified my sentence.

Comment: It might be helpful to note that $t \geq \tau$ for some $t \in [0,\infty)$ implies $x^{-1}(B)=I \neq \emptyset$

Answer (score 0):

If $E$ is a topological space, $B$ is closed and $f$ is right-continuous, we can show that either

1. $\tau\in I$; or
2. $I=\emptyset$ and hence $\tau=\infty$.

With this result, it is easy to conclude the desired implication from $(4)$.

Comment: It is true, but you should actually prove that $\tau \in I$ when $I \ne \emptyset$. The proof of this fact is close to mine.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I don't understand what you mean. As I wrote in my answer: It does hold either (1.) or (2.). And this immediately implies that $\tau\in I$ when $I\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: Just prove that 1 or 2 holds.